# Combine 2 queries into one

Tags: powerbi, dax

In the following dax query I have it working by creating 2 separate tables **security_tbl_country** and **security_tbl_state**. They use the same input table **access**. I can't seem to figure out how to do it with just 1 calculatetable.

The pseudocode I would like:

```
accessSubset = {access records where access[e-mail] = upn()}

If (accessSubset[type] = "country" and Fact[geo] in accessSubset[name]) 
or 
(accessSubset[type] = "state" and Fact[state] in accessSubset[name])
  Return true
Else 
  Return false
```

Dax that I have working, but using 2 calculateTables

```
VAR upn = USERPRINCIPALNAME() //xxx@ab.com
VAR security_tbl_country = CALCULATETABLE(
  VALUES('Access'[Name]),
  FILTER(
    'Access',
    'Access'[E-mail] = upn && 'Access'[Type] = "Country"
  )
)
VAR security_tbl_state = CALCULATETABLE(
  VALUES('Access'[Name]),
  FILTER(
    'Access',
    'Access'[E-mail] = upn && 'Access'[Type] = "State"
  )
)
RETURN
  'Facts'[Country] IN security_tbl_country || 'Facts'[State] IN security_tbl_state
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
var userAccess = 
  SUMMARIZE(
    FILTER('Access', [Email] = USERPRINCIPALNAME()),
    Access[Type], Access[Name]
  )
RETURN
  COUNTROWS(FILTER(userAccess, [Type] = "Country" && [Name] = 'Facts'[Country])) > 0
  ||
  COUNTROWS(FILTER(userAccess, [Type] = "State" && [Name] = 'Facts'[State])) > 0
```

Comment: This is definitely more readable than my DAX

Comment: Assuming this is for RLS, I would suggest having a `Dim Georgraphy` table and you apply the RLS to this. Then have a one-to-many relationship to your `Facts` table. This will be far more performant then applying RLS directly on a Fact table.

Comment: this is for rls. But as the type on access table defines which field to filter against the fact table, and there are more types than just the 2 defined here, (and they aren't just geography) we were looking for a formula based approach. But your point about performance is heeded

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simplification I found for the above query (though I dont know if it is more readable or any faster)

```
VAR upn = USERPRINCIPALNAME() //xxx@ab.com
VAR security_tbl = CALCULATETABLE(
  SELECTCOLUMNS('Access',[Name], [Type]),
  FILTER(
    'Access',
    [E-mail] = upn
  )
)
RETURN
  'Facts'[Country] IN SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(security_tbl,[Type] = "Country"),[Name]) 
   || 'Facts'[State] IN SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(security_tbl,[Type] = "State"),[Name])
```